# How best to package rubygems in addition to jruby-complete.jar?

Tags: rubygems, jruby

As developing an Java application bundled with 'jruby-complete.jar', it is desired not to put required rubygems localally, but instead packaged it along with the application. Obviously we don't want to touch 'jruby-complete.jar'. What's the better way of packaging these rubygems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's an answer for you in this post:

[Gems-in-a-jar](http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2009/01/10/jruby-1-1-6-gems-in-a-jar)

> Obviously we don't want to touch 'jruby-complete.jar'.

I'm curious...  Why not?

Comment: for first, it's a 3rd party library. second, we already have other jar libraries so we don't really require a single jar. third, it's already a very large file.